# WordPress error: Call to undefined function require_wp_db()

Tags: wordpress, call, fatal-error

This started with the white screen of death. I cannot even get into `wp-admin`. I did not upgrade WP, did not load a new theme or a new plugin. Here is what I tried to fix it:

- shutting down plugins
- removing my custom theme
- defining bigger memory in `wp-config`
- removing white space in `functions.php` (even though I haven't touched it)
- put error checking in `wp-config`. I get the errors:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in /home/youradmi/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 650
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in /home/youradmi/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 665
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in /home/youradmi/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 672
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in /home/youradmi/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 679
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in /home/youradmi/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 715
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function require_wp_db() in
>   /home/youradmi/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 273

I started with the "Call to undefined function r`equire_wp_db()`" since it occurs first. Here is the line:

```
 require_wp_db();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know if the PHP version was updated?

Comment: Thank for answering. No PHP wasn't updated.

Comment: I contacted my web host to see if they updated PHP without informing us.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're running an older version of wordpress.  I wouldn't worry about the deprecation messages.  As Tomas suggested, your php version may have been updated.  Those are just warnings meaning that at some point that code will stop working, but right now it will still work.

You could spend ages trying to figure out what went wrong, or you could just install a new copy of wordpress.

1. Move all existing wordpress files to a subdirectory (e.g. 'backup').
2. Install new wordpress
3. copy backup/wp-config.php into new wp location
4. copy plugins, uploads, themes from backup to new wp

When you login to the backend, your database will be upgraded automatically for the new version of wp.